# Does pyvenv replace virtualenv in python3.3 +?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.3

I just read about [`pyvenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which is included in Python 3.3 per [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#backwards-compatibility).

It looks like it provides the same directory structure and the same usage as `virtualenv`. Is there some difference I'm missing or starting with Python 3.3, does `pyvenv` replace `virtualenv`?

The documentation states:

> Their concept and implementation are inspired by the popular
>   virtualenv third-party package, but benefit from tighter integration
>   with the interpreter core.

So are they just saying it's the same thing?

Comment: There is really no further factual information than the page you're already reading (and maybe [PEP 405](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)). If you have specific questions about either `venv` or `virtualenv` we can ask those, but if you're just asking for opinions or commentary, SO is not an appropriate place for that.

Comment: I was trying to understand the differences between these two tools as well and i find this question helpful and not at all calling for opinion based conversation. I think this might be the answer that the author was looking for: http://homework.nwsnet.de/releases/8aff/

Comment: The answer is no. Virtualenv depends on venv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911070/does-using-virtualenvwrapper-with-python3-3-mean-i-cannot-or-should-not-be-usi?rq=1